# JQuery 1.5 selector error

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-1.5

Since, upgrading to JQuery 1.5, the following selector no longer works:

```
var selectedTab = $('div.menu > ul > li > a[href=service.html]');
```

The error message is:

> uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [href=service.html]

Is this a bug in the latest version of JQuery or (much more likely) a dormant bug in my code?

Comment: I think it's a dormant bug, as this was the preferred coding standard since 1.3, if I'm not mistaken. 1.3 & 1.4 was just way more lenient in that regard.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to quote the value:

```
$('div.menu > ul > li > a[href="service.html"]')
```